# Is there a Developer and Inspect feature in Mail.app

Tags: mail.app, web-inspector

Is there a Developer and Inspect feature in Mail.app?

Within Safari.app, I have a developer menu which includes an Inspect item which allows me to investigate issues with HTML in the browser.

Does such a feature exist in the Mail.app?

Comment: Which Mail.app - iOS or OS X? What version of the OS?

Comment: macOS - /Applications/Mail.app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, other than the Raw Source.

Comment: This should be the selected answer.

Answer (score 4):

To inspect the underlying code of a message, you can use View > Message > Raw Source.

Comment: Sorry, Not what I was looking for.   Viewing source (available using Alt-Cmd U) is helpful and also available in Safari - but it is not the developer inspect feature.